# find a control with no runat='server' from server side

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

my code :

```
<div id="conversationdiv" runat="server">
 <table border="1" id="table_id">
  <tr>
   <td>blah blah</td>
    </tr>
   </table>
</div>
<asp:button id='clickMe' runat='server' onClick="Click_me" Text="appendRow"></asp:Button>
```

ServerSIde:

```
protected void Click_me(object sender,EventArgs e){
  HtmlTable table = (HtmlTable)ConversationDIv.FindControl("table_id");
 }
```

the HtmlTable table return null and i know it's because there is no `runat='server'` attribute for the table, but my question is there a way that can I still find the table even if no such attribute added ?

Comment: No, you cannot find control that represents this table, since this is not a control. You can access `conversationdiv.InnerHtml`, but that would be only a string.

Comment: It's been a while since I was in ASP.NET, but assigning `runat="server"` should make that div an `HtmlGenericControl` which would lend itself to `.Controls` (therefore allowing you access to the nested table)--no? if not there is `.InnerHtml` but then you're getting in to HTML parsing yourself.

Comment: Sounds silly but... why not just adding ID and `runat="server"` to the table? It will solve your "problem" in the most elegant way.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, most likely it is being generated and OP does not have a direct control over it - otherwise question would not raise I believe. Just guessing though.

Comment: @Andrei might be, but might as well be something like "because I don't know how to access this from the code behind" then we can guide the OP on the correct path.

Comment: i maybe had giving just a small example and not the real code to make it easy to understand my problem is that the table is getting generated from code behind as a string and then i'm appending it to the div innerHTML to have this final form but than i wanted to a add a new row and that where the problem starts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do `conversationdiv.InnerHtml`... in this specific case it would return the *HTML of the* table.

You could then use HTML Agility Pack to query or manipulate the said table.

---

**Example**

```
var html = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

html.LoadHtml(conversationdiv.InnerHtml);

var table = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("table").FirstOrDefault();

var tr = table.SelectNodes("tr").FirstOrDefault();

var td = tr.SelectNodes("td").FirstOrDefault();

var blahBlah = td.InnerText;
```

Comment: @Sora Hope it helps! There's plenty of documentation on HTML Agility Pack so you should be able to figure it out from here :)